# Nested lookup and substitute System properties in log4j2 properties file

Tags: java, configuration, log4j, log4j2, lookup

In log4j2.properties file we have following definition to accept dynamic file path via System property log.filePath

```
appender.file.fileName=${sys:log.filePath}
```

In JAVA layer before creation of Logger instance we are replacing log.filePath System property with actual value

```
System.setProperty("log.filePath" + logfilePath);
```

We would like to ensure if System property log.filePath is not available/replaced, then want to create the log file in java.io.tmpdir directory with name app.log.

As per Log4j2 System Properties Lookup doc https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html following syntax exists `fileName="${sys:logPath:-/var/logs}/app.log"` to create default log in /var/logs/app.log

Considering both Unix and Windows environment we would like to use java.io.tmpdir System property instead of /var/logs directory

I have tried multiple combination of following syntaxes but not works

```
fileName="${sys:logPath:-sys:java.io.tmpdir}/app.log"
```

Can someone please suggest if using a System property for lookup default value is supported?

Comment: `$${env:log.filePath:-env:java.io.tmpdir} ` might work per their docs

Comment: no luck with this.

Comment: So what *exactly* was the `<PatternLayout>` node in your attempt?

Comment: I am using log4j2.properties file not .xml file. Following are the configuration options for fileName and layout

appender.file.fileName=${sys:log.filePath}

appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout

appender.file.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%5p] %t (%c) - %m%n

Comment: You're going to have to use the XML form most probably. In any case,  it's preferable to using a properties file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fallback value after `:-` is treated as a literal, but accepts nested lookups. So you have two choices:

- use `${sys:logPath:-${sys:java.io.tmpdir}}`,
- or define a configuration property named `logPath` (the default fallback for `${sys:logPath}` is `${logPath}`):

  ```xml
  <Properties>
    <Property name="logPath" value="${sys:java.io.tmpdir}"/>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <File fileName="${sys:logPath}/app.log" .../>
  </Appenders>
  ```

Comment: My syntax usage attempt was incorrect. Thanks, I tried option1 and it works.